# What is wrong in my mocha test with .done()?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

In my mocha test I have something like this

```
it.only("diag", function(done) {
        let data = null;
        app.client.timeoutsAsyncScript(5000).executeAsync(function(data, done) {
            console.log("START");
            done();
        });
    });
```

In my application I can see that console.log has been done. But this function .done() was never called. Why ? What could be wrong ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are having a scope naming issue. Have a look at [this page](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch2.md) for more information on how variables work in scopes.

Answer (score 1):

You have parameter with the same name **"done"** in your callback function. The variable from the local scope is used over the variable from outer scope. You can either remove it or rename it e.g. `executeAsync(function(data, done2) { ...`